In Kotlin, why doesn't cancelling work as expected when there is no suspension point in the coroutine?
Consider this code in Kotlin:
launch {
    // If we comment 'cancel()' console shows:
    //    B
    //    C
    //    A
    // So there is no suspension point.
    cancel()
    launch { println("A") } // Will not be printed
    coroutineScope { println("B") }
    println("C") // Will not be printed
}.join()

Why coroutine gets cancelled here even without any suspension point?
I expect "cancel()" command should never happen because there is no actual suspension point there. But it actually cancels the coroutine after executing the coroutineScope function (and printing B). If you comment the "cancel()" command and run the code, you can see that the coroutine never gets suspended (since the order of print is B, C, A).
I guess "cancellation" should work once coroutine is suspended (it does not act immediately); why coroutine gets cancelled here? Do you have any explanation for it?

First of all, your code contains a suspension point. coroutineScope is a suspend function, so calling it creates a suspension point in the calling function.
Second, I don't think cancelling is based on suspension points. Many suspending functions check cancellations, so it may look like cancelling happens when suspending, but I believe these two topics aren't that much related. Cancelling is cooperative, it is handled by the cancelled coroutine, not by suspending.  We can provide examples of both cancelling without suspension points, e.g. ensureActive and examples of suspending that ignores cancelling, e.g. suspendCoroutine.

Many thanks for your valuable comment. But I guess despite the fact that a coroutineScope being suspend function, there is no actual suspension point in it so it won't get suspended here. This is why "A" is not printed before "C" when you comment "cancel()". In case of suspension on the coroutineScope, letter "A" should be written before "C" I believe.

and I think ensureActive is used when the coroutine is already cancelled but still running (till a suspension point?). Am I wrong?

What is your understanding of a "suspension point"? Whenever we call a suspend function, the Kotlin compiler adds a code that allows to suspend at this point and resume later. This is because if the called function needs to suspend, the execution of the caller function also has to suspend. Cancellatons in coroutines are handled by checking the internal status and throwing an exception. Any function can do it, no matter suspendable or not. Also, ordering between A and B is not guaranteed in your example.

I think a suspension point is where a function really gets suspended (not potentially) and in that case all launched coroutines before that suspension point will start running until they get suspended or finished. Then codes continues till the next suspension or end of the scope. This is why I said if it was suspended, "A" would be printed before "C". Anyway, as you said, probably coroutineScope internally checks if the coroutine is cancelled even when I don't have any code suspended in it. Thanks.
